# How to simplify jquery code with variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, toggle, simplify

I have this jQuery code I've done to toggle floating sections with image previews. The layer is always the same, only the images change. I've manage to simplify the code in css giving classes to the elements. Everything works fine. However I'm finding it very hard to optimize the jQuery code. I'm pretty new to jQuery and Javascript so I'm not quite sure how to do this. The code works fine but It's massive huge and I want to simplify it. I believe I have to use variables. But how? Any help would be appreciated :)

this is my jQuery code:

```
//first layer

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggleLayer').click(function(){
$('#FloatingLayer').fadeIn('fast');
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#FloatingLayer').click(function(){
$(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
});


//second layer

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggleLayer2').click(function(){
$('#FloatingLayer2').fadeIn('fast');
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#FloatingLayer2').click(function(){
$(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
});



// third layer

$(document).ready(function() {
$('.toggleLayer3').click(function(){
$('#FloatingLayer3').fadeIn('fast');
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#FloatingLayer3').click(function(){
$(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
});
```

And here is my html:

```
<div class="fourcol toggleLayer">   
     <img src="img1" class="center" width="100%">
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol toggleLayer2">   
     <img src="img2.jpg" class="center" width="100%">
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol toggleLayer3">   
     <img src="img3" class="center" width="100%" >
  </div>
```

the floating sections:

```
<section class="Floating" id="FloatingLayer">
     <img src="img1.jpg" class="floatimg"/>
   </section>

   <section class="Floating" id="FloatingLayer2">
     <img src="img2.jpg" class="floatimg"/>
   </section>

  <section class="Floating" id="FloatingLayer3">
     <img src="img3.jpg" class="floatimg"/>
   </section>
```

Comment: Where's the markup for the "toggle-layer" elements? are they buttons or something?

Comment: You're right! I'm sorry. I've edited the question and added that.

Comment: OK I'll edit my answer to use your markup; same basic idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take advantage of the fact that you can add information to your markup that guides behaviors supplied by your JavaScript code. Assuming your toggle controls are buttons:

```
<button class=toggle-layer data-target=FloatingLayer1>Layer 1</button>
<button class=toggle-layer data-target=FloatingLayer2>Layer 2</button>
<button class=toggle-layer data-target=FloatingLayer3>Layer 3</button>
```

*edit* — or with your actual markup:

```
  <div class="fourcol toggleLayer" data-target=FloatingLayer1>   
     <img src="img1" class="center" width="100%">
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol toggleLayer" data-target=FloatingLayer2>   
     <img src="img2.jpg" class="center" width="100%">
  </div>

  <div class="fourcol toggleLayer" data-target=FloatingLayer3>   
     <img src="img3" class="center" width="100%" >
  </div>
```

You now can write one simple handler for all of them:

```
$("body").on("click", ".toggleLayer", function() {
  var targetId = $(this).data("target");

  $("#" + targetId).fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Similarly, one handler can do the work to close all the layers:

```
$("body").on("click", ".Floating", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

If you use event delegation as in these examples, you don't have to put the code in a "ready" handler.

Comment: Thank you! However, I must be doing something wrong. I used that code and it stopped working :(

Comment: @Owly well I could have made some dumb mistake; if you post the errors you're getting it may be easy to fix.

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't give me any errors in the console. It just doesn't do anything when I click. Nothing happens. I'll edit my question with the code I've got now so you see.

Comment: @Owly OK I updated the answer to more closely match your classes. I'm not sure what's going wrong; if you're not getting errors, the first thing I'd do is put some `console.log()` calls in the event handlers to see it anything's happening there.

Comment: @Owly [here is a working CodePen based directly on your markup and the two event handlers in my answer.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/Wbvexo)

Comment: @Owly one thing I just thought of: if there's a "click" handler for some element that contains the "toggle" elements, and it cancels propagation, then that would prevent the delegated event handlers from working.

Comment: OMG I just found out what was wrong. Thank you! It was my mistake. Your code was correct and it works perfectly. The problem was that I typed data-target="FloatingLayer1" insted of data-target=FloatingLayer1 . I added the "" for no reason! Thank you so much for your time and help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Without changing your markup at all...

```
var $body = $(document.body);

$body.on('click', '[class~=toggleLayer]', function () {
    var layerNum = this.className.match(/toggleLayer(\d+)/)[1];

    $('#FloatingLayer' + layerNum).fadeIn('fast');
});

$body.on('click', '.Floating', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast');
});
```

However, the behavior is not explicit here and it would be better to modify your markup and use custom `data-` attributes like suggested by Pointy.